# Skip stages is not working using azure devops rest api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a very basic pipeline with 4 stages, for prod stage i want to run from separate pipeline . I was trying to use [build queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api as per documentation and using below payload

```
{
"stagesToSkip": [
    "Build"
],
"definition":
{
    "id": "24"
},
"resources": {
    "repositories": {
        "self": {
            "refName": "refs/heads/master"
        }
    }
},
"variables": {}
```

}

I got this payload when i manually run the build by selecting only one stage and run it works as expected as highlighted but whn i use the rest api with the same request payload , it runs both the stages.

[image]

any pointers what i'm doing wrong??

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check below rest api. How did it go with you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api to skip stages.

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1`

See below example in powershell script:

```
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1"

$PAT='personal access token'

$body='{
 
 "stagesToSkip":[ "Test" ]

}'

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$result1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method post  -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
```

See below test result. The stage was successfully skipped.

[image]