# Azure Pipeline - Skip Stages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a main pipeline where I choose which stages should be triggered. This main pipeline calls other pipelines. From these pipelines there should also just be triggered the stage from the main one. I found that there is a `stagesToSkip` parameter. But it doesn't matter what I choose there. There will all be triggered all stages in the called pipeline. What is the error?

```cs
$targetEnvironment = 'dev'

$stages = @("dev", "staging", "prod") | Where-Object { $_ -ne $targetEnvironment } | ConvertTo-Json
$body = "{
    `"stagesToSkip`" : $(ConvertTo-Json($stages))
}"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip stages is not working using azure devops rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62786533/skip-stages-is-not-working-using-azure-devops-rest-api)

Comment: I have done it like in the link. I could find my mistake. `$stages` is already an `Array`. So the snippet has just to be `"stagesToSkip`" : $stages

Comment: It would be better if it's possible to say which stages should be runned and not which ones has to be skipped. But that's another topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have done it like in the link. I could find my mistake. $stages is already an Array. So the snippet has just to be "stagesToSkip" : $stages

Yes, you need to fix the `stagesToSkip` value. I added the sample below, which will only trigger the target environment dev stage, and skip staging, prod stages.

```
pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

steps:
- checkout: none
- powershell: |
    $url="https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineid}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
    $targetEnvironment = 'dev'

    $stages = @("dev", "staging", "prod") | Where-Object { $_ -ne $targetEnvironment } | ConvertTo-Json
    $body = "{
        `"stagesToSkip`" : $stages
    }"
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json
```

Only run the target dev stage:

[image]

I used system.acccesstoken instead of pat, just need to grant `queue builds` permission for the build service account on target pipeline.

[image]

Regarding your new query:

> It would be better if it's possible to say which stages should be runned and not which ones has to be skipped.

You can use rest api [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to trigger the target pipeline, meanwhile transfer the parameter which contains the target stages. On the target pipeline, run the stages with conditions.

sample as below, main yaml, please replace target pipeline definition id with yours.

```
pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

parameters:
- name: stages
  type: string
  default: dev, staging, prod

steps:
- checkout: none

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $body = '
      { 
              "definition": {
                  "id": 401         
              },
              "templateParameters": {
                "stages": "${{ parameters.stages}}"
             }
      }
      '

      $Uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=7.1-preview.7"
      $buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $Uri -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"}
      write-host $buildresponse
```

Target pipeline:

```
parameters:
- name: stages
  type: string

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  stageList: ${{parameters.stages}}

stages:
- stage: dev
  condition: contains(variables.stageList, 'dev')
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - bash: echo "A"

- stage: staging
  condition: contains(variables.stageList, 'staging')
  jobs:
  - job: B
    steps:
    - bash: echo "B"

- stage: prod
  condition: contains(variables.stageList, 'prod')
  jobs:
  - job: C
    steps:
    - bash: echo "C"
```

When i run the main pipeline, **can specify the stages to run**:
[image]

Target pipeline triggered, without staging stage.

[image]